# Error trying to send email with C# Library SendGrid

Tags: twilio, sendgrid

I'm trying to send email through the sendgrid library for C#, in my development environment it works perfectly, but when I move to my quality environment the following error is occurring, has anyone experienced this before? this error occurs when I call the SendEmailAsync method

> {"Message":"Erro: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at SendGrid.Helpers.Reliability.RetryDelegatingHandler.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at SendGrid.BaseClient.d__20.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at SendGrid.BaseClient.d__21.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at SendGrid.BaseClient.d__22.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n

Initially I thought it might be a permission problem, but I created another site on the same server that only sends the email and it works, it seems something related to my project, but I couldn't find out what it could be...

i Forgot put the code, Error occurs on line:

> _client.SendEmailAsync(emailMessage).Result

```
public EmailResponse Send(EmailContract contract)
{
    var emailMessage = new SendGridMessage()
    {
        From = new EmailAddress(contract.FromEmailAddress, 
contract.Alias),
        Subject = contract.Subject,
        HtmlContent = contract.Body,
        PlainTextContent = contract.Body
    };

    emailMessage.AddTo(new EmailAddress(contract.ToEmailAddress));
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contract.BccEmailAddress))
    {
        emailMessage.AddBcc(new 
EmailAddress(contract.BccEmailAddress));
    }

   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contract.CcEmailAddress))
   {
        emailMessage.AddCc(new EmailAddress(contract.CcEmailAddress));
    }
    return 
ProcessResponse(_client.SendEmailAsync(emailMessage).Result);
}
```

Comment: Please add your code, and do not let the reader on stackoverflow.com guess what you did to get this error.

Comment: of course, sorry I forgot...

Comment: I found the problem, it was happening due to the TLS version that the framework was using, apparently the version that Sendgrid accepts is 1.2, so I had to force it to that version and it worked perfectly. the sendgrid library uses the protocol "under the hood"